# Item accessible only via display name

Tags: pipelines, link-manager

As I know, by default, an item is accessible both via name and display name.
This creates SEO issue because there is duplicate content.
Is there a simple way to disable access via name or I need to hook the ItemResolver?

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is just handled by adding canonical urls so Search engines know that the page is the same page even if referenced with upper/lowercase/displayname/trailing slash etc.

This is not a Sitecore specific thing though. This article describes this further and how to implement this for Sitecore depending on your scenario:

https://blog.mastykarz.nl/optimizing-sitecore-internet-search-engines-canonical-urls/

Simple MVC Helper method from above link:

```
public static System.Web.HtmlString CanonicalUrl(this Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper sitecoreHelper) {
    Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions urlOptions = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlOptions();
    urlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;

    string canonicalUrl = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item, urlOptions);

    return new System.Web.HtmlString(canonicalUrl);
}
```

Then to Render the link:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="@Html.Sitecore().CanonicalUrl()">
```